# How insert an XML in a command line

Tags: php, xml, command-line

I have already a script that's needed a formatted XML lines to be executed. When I try to call it via the command line, the CL window throws me an error.

```
parse error near `<'
```

Here's the full example :

```
docker exec -itu www-data php_test php import.php <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><import><media><code>FAF</code></media></import>
```

Comment: Pretty sure you need to surround your xml with quotes. You cannot use double quotes since your string consists of it. So either use single quotes if linux accepts that. Or use double quotes, and escape the quotes in your string